# trying to assign value to schema in schema in mongoose in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so my mongoose model looks like this

```
 userName:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    userEmail:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    userGym: gySchema,
    userPassword:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
```

gySchema is another schema and through patch method of https I am trying to assign a value to a variable in gySchema in Nodejs, how can I do so??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code for your reference as I too have done a project using this. When your using `patch` you have to just use `req.body` as it is what you want to update. and the **route** will be `req.patch`. `patch` is for partial update. `put` is for entire update.

`model`

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Genre, validateGenre, genreSchema } = require("./genre");
Joi.objectId = require("joi-objectid")(Joi);

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50,
    },
    numberInStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 255,
        default: 13,
    },
    dailyRentalRate: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 255,
        required: true,
    },
    liked: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    genre: {
        type: genreSchema,
        required: true,
    },
});

const Movie = mongoose.model("Movie", movieSchema);

function validateMovie(movie) {
    const schema = {
        title: Joi.string().required().min(5).max(255),
        numberInStock: Joi.number().required().min(0).max(255),
        dailyRentalRate: Joi.number().required().min(0).max(255),
        liked: Joi.boolean(),
        genreId: Joi.objectId().required(),
        _id: Joi.objectId(),
    };
    return Joi.validate(movie, schema);
}

module.exports.Movie = Movie;
module.exports.validateMovie = validateMovie;
```

`routes`

```
const express = require("express");
const { Movie, validateMovie } = require("../models/movie");
const { Genre } = require("../models/genre");
const auth = require("../middlewares/auth");
const admin = require("../middlewares/admin");
const validateObjectId = require("../middlewares/validateObjectId");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const movies = await Movie.find();    
    res.send(movies);
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    //validate the movie
    const { error } = validateMovie(req.body);
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }

    const genre = await Genre.findById(req.body.genreId);
    if (!genre) {
        return res.status(400).send("No genre found with given id");
    }

    const movie = new Movie({
        title: req.body.title,
        numberInStock: req.body.numberInStock,
        dailyRentalRate: req.body.dailyRentalRate,
        liked: req.body.liked,
        genre: {
            _id: genre._id,
            name: genre.name,
        },
    });

    // console.log(movies);
    await movie.save();
    console.log("Saving the document...");
    res.send(movie);
});

//updating
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validateMovie(req.body);
    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }

    let genre = await Genre.findById(req.body.genreId);
    console.log(genre);
    if (!genre) {
        return res.status(400).send("No genre found with given id");
    }

    let movieDetails = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {
            title: req.body.title,
            numberInStock: req.body.numberInStock,
            dailyRentalRate: req.body.dailyRentalRate,
            liked: req.body.liked,
            genre: {
                _id: genre.id,
                name: genre.name,
            },
        }, //when using patch method, then u need not have to write this whole thing. instead just write req.body
        { new: true }
    );

    if (!movieDetails) {
        return res.status(404).send("No such movie details found.");
    }

    res.send(movieDetails);
});

router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    let movieDetails = await Movie.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

    if (!movieDetails) {
        return res.status(404).send("No id found for given Movie");
    }

    res.send(movieDetails);
});

module.exports = router;
```